# Changing some system file values in Android failing

Tags: android, file, usb, system, root

I am trying to change some sys values but I don't seem to be having much success.

In my case I am trying to change values of files in the folder

"/sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0"

e.g. the file bInterfaceClass which currently has value 09

My tries:
(In shell, as root)

```
chmod 777 bInterfaceClass
echo 07 >> bInterfaceClass
```

I didn't receive an error but when looking up the value

```
cat bInterfaceClass
```

It is still 09

Now looking up this file in Root Explorer, I can see that the last modification date of the file has changed, so my guess: something resets the value of such a sys file as soon as it changes. Can anyone shine some more light on this issue? How can I change the value?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is a good question, but it's unrelated to programming. You'll have better luck asking on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok will give it a try over @ androidstackexchange.com, but also still hoping someone might be able to help me out here

Comment: `echo 07 > bInterfaceClass` maybe, `>>` would be appending data to that file, `>` is overwriting

Comment: I've had success using echo >> with other system files, but, you never know ... so I also tried >, but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS IS HACKERY, you have been warned! :)**

Instructions here are not generally found on the Internet, but can be great for testing interfaces and capabilities without significantly changing system code. THESE CAN BE USED TO ADDRESS ANYTHING WHICH IS BEING OVERWRITTEN without warning or cause. Using these, you can sometimes see based off of using `dmesg` `ps` and `logcat`what exactly is causing you so many problems, while testing a solution.

The is likely in the Kernel with things like this getting written over, maybe a system service or script internally. A quality perm fix would be in the /drivers folder of the kernel. I can only assume this is on a Beagle or Panda Board, maybe a Moto device. If it is Beagle or Panda, this will be easier (yay Linaro, AOSP support, big community!).

If this is something that does not need to Hold USB open, but merely have the desired number present you can try below:

Open up your boot.img and open he Root Disk/Ramdisk and finally one of your init..rc files. You can use this tool: **https://github.com/dsixda/Android-Kitchen**  - requires Linux and a few packages, great tool!

If you are lucky, this will appear as part of the `init.rc` files (which you can check in-system) or in the `/system/etc` folder as one of the class main or core scripts.

You can declare the value you want if you look for it in the:

on init

Section of the **init.platform.rc** and look where

**/sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0**

is initialized,

then in the .rc file

```
chmod 777 /sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0/bInterfaceClass
write /sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0/bInterfaceClass 07
```

Then if doing that and initializing it as such does not hold by that alone, open the normal init.rc and add

```
on nonencrypted 
write /sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0/bInterfaceClass 07
```

and also

```
on property:vold.decrypt=trigger_shutdown_framework
write /sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0/bInterfaceClass 07
```

as those two properties or functions will cover you at the end of the inits to set that property again (you already gave it 777 privilages earlier as part of the on init)

If you want something you can play with without flashing new Boot.img files:

Declare your script in the system/bin as a service in the init.platform.rc (don't worry most every .rc file is linked and includes each other) using:

```
service usbchanger /system/bin/sh /system/bin/usbchanger.sh
      class late_start
      user root   
      disabled
```

Then in the normal init.rc

```
on nonencrypted 
     start usbchanger

on property:vold.decrypt=trigger_shutdown_framework
     start usbchanger
```

Your script will then become a constantly running service (you can do the same with a binary). This is totally a desired trait when doing debugging and testing new features/fixes because you can change the values and running commands while the system is open and does not require you to re-flash after every change. However, for production you should not have this going. Its bad code to do that generally when really, it should be in the `kernel` or core.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I decided to see what results the "not flashing new boot.img" method would give me, but when reading the bInterfaceClass value this is still 09. Even though I can see I have Usbchanger service running. The shellscript contains:
"chmod 777 /sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0/bInterfaceClass echo 07 >> /sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0/bInterfaceClass" I don't think I'm missing smth, so I'll dive into my linux OS and see what I can cook up. As some kernel changes will probably solve this matter, I accept this answer!